# How to stop terminal in ue4

Tags: function, if-statement, terminal

Hi i got very simple game in UE4 which are guessing I make static mesh and added terminal to it so
its showing
now, when player runs out live it should end i got it like

```
void UBullCowCartridge::BeginPlay() // When the game starts
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    PrintLine(TEXT("DEV: Slovo je: "));
    PrintLine(TEXT("Riskuj"));
    PrintLine(TEXT("Budes hadat slovo"));
    PrintLine(TEXT("Mas 5 zivotu slovo je ISOGram (pismenka ve"));
    PrintLine(TEXT("slove se neopakuji)"));
    PrintLine(TEXT("pokud nejake pismeno bude dobre pricte se ti byk pokud nejake spatne pricte se ti"));
    PrintLine(TEXT("krava"));
    PrintLine(TEXT("Zacnes psat pomoci TAB tlacitka."));
    HiddenWord = TEXT("Svoboda");

}

void UBullCowCartridge::OnInput(const FString& Input) // When the player hits enter
{
    ClearScreen();
    if(Input == HiddenWord)
    {
        PrintLine(TEXT("You win!"));
    } else {
        PrintLine(TEXT("You lose"));
        --live;
    }

    if(live == 0) {
        end();      
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to set invisible the "terminal" static mesh. In this case you could do like this:

```
//don't forget cast the class containing mesh component

terminal_static_mesh_component->SetVisibility(false);
```